# Sequelize include related model on extended foreign key

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Say I have a db structure with a chain of foreign keys:
**User**, fk: -->  **Photo**, fk --> **Color**

In Sequelize I want to select all Users, and get all of their photos, along with the color of each photo.

ex:
It is easy to get just the photos by saying:

```
models.User.findAll({
    include: [{model: models.Photo, as: 'mainPhoto'}]
})
```

But how do I also get the color of each of those photos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using below :

```
models.User.findAll({
    include: [{model: models.Photo, as: 'mainPhoto', include : [{model: models.Color, as 'photoColor'}]}]
})
```